# Can you insert tables themselves to another table?

Tags: sql-server, datatable

So I decided to experiment SQL via nesting a table into another.

This might complicate you, so I'll need some explaining.

I just started using SQL once again and I want to try some nesting techniques.

What I want to do is to select a whole table (T1) and insert it to another table (T2) in a single plot of T2 whereas the data from T1 is still kept.

I still have little knowledge about SQL, and I decided to make some draft first:

```sql
CREATE TABLE InnerTable 
{
    blah blah blah;
};

CREATE TABLE OuterTable 
{
    blah blah blah;
}

INSERT INTO OuterTable (blah blah blah) VALUES (blah blah blah);
INSERT INTO InnerTable (blah blah blah) VALUES (blah blah blah);
INSERT INTO OuterTable (blah blah blah) VALUES (InnerTable);
```

Then I also read [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/nesting-levels-in-sql/) which doesn't seem like what I wanted to do.

And now I have to figure out how to make the program functional and do what I wanted.

Is there a way to insert a table inside another?

Comment: `INSERT INTO OuterTable (blah, blah, blah) SELECT blah, blah, blah FROM InnerTable`

Comment: @Fabio Does that select the whole `InnerTable`to be put in the `OuterTable`?

Comment: If by "whole" you mean all rows than yes. You can insert only some rows by adding `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Hold on, I'll try it later.

Comment: Just as a side note: you need to use **round brackets** (parenthesis) in your `CREATE TABLE` statements - not curly braces......

Comment: Okay, understood.